# How to simulate a user with certain permissions using WebTest

Tags: django, python-2.7, webtest

I'm testing my views and would like to simulate logged in user with certain permissions.

I know that in django-webtest I can simulate logged in user like this:

```
self.app.get(reverse('profile'), user='bob')
```

Can i also pass in a group for this user? Or a list of permissions?
If i will create a user in setUp and assign a group to him, can i simulate him logged in by passing his username like this:

```
self.app.get(reverse('profile'), user='user_with_certain_permissions')
```

or do i need to log him in first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this should work. You may also pass User instance instead of username:

```
self.app.get(reverse("profile"), self.user_with_certain_permissions)
```

Comment: Thank you. What got me confused a bit is that 'bob' was not created in setUp. There is no User with such name, and still it worked. It got me wondering if I can simulate a user with permissions same way.

Comment: The example in django-webtest docs assumes the user came from fixtures (``fixtures = ['users', 'blog_posts']``).

Comment: Well, that's the thing. In my case there is no user 'bob', and still it worked. I ran a test to get a page that has login_required decorator, and it worked. I ran same test with no user supplied and indeed i was redirected to login page. I also know i don't have any other user logged in, b.c this is a test in its own, so tear down was executed and new setup is in order. Unless django-webtest loads its own fixtures...

Comment: django-webtest uses a subclass of django's RemoteUserBackend auth backend, and RemoteUserBackend creates User instances for unknown users by default. This is counter-intuitive indeed.

Comment: oh, i see. This certainly explains this behavior i was getting. Thank you :)